# RESTlet 2.1 can't get client certificate

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I recently updated restlet to version 2.1 and I'm no longer able to get the client certificate. I'm using the new way to get client certificate

```
List<Certificate> r =  getRequest().getClientInfo().getCertificates();
```

I'm using CURL to send my authentication info

```
curl -k -E admin.pem https://localhost:8111/profile -v
```

Any idea why this doesn't work in restlet 2.1 ?

Comment: Expereincing the same as you. Any changes two years later?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to version 2.2 which changed the internal HTTP connector and should restore this property.