# Getting client certificate in restlet

Tags: ssl, restlet

I managed to implement an https restlet with bot client and server certificated. I can prove it works since if I call the server with an untrusted certification communication fails. Unfortunately I can't find the certificate of the client on the server. I'm using this code:

```
List<Certificate> certs = request.getClientInfo().getCertificates();
```

but list is empty. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

version is **Restlet-Framework/2.3m2**

Comment: this guy upgraded to 2.1 and had the same problem.  No answer :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048855/restlet-2-1-cant-get-client-certificate

Comment: does request.getAttributes()..get("org.restlet.https.clientCertificates");
 work?

Comment: @tom Unfortunately it does not work too. AFAIK under the hood the call done by getCerificates rely on that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the use of the default server implementation via `com.sun.httpserver`.
The class `org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpExchangeCall` should return the certificates in the `getCertificates()` method,
but it always returns `null`. This class is used in `org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpsServerHelper`
which in turn is the helper for the Restlet framework when using the server implementation `com.sun.httpserver`.

To fix this, a couple of things are needed.

First, a new class `HttpsExchangeCall`:

```java
package org.restlet.engine.connector;

import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.restlet.Server;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsExchange;

/**
 * The default {@link HttpExchangeCall} fails to extract certificates from the SSL connection.
 * This class implements {@link #getCertificates()} to extract certificates.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class HttpsExchangeCall extends HttpExchangeCall {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpsExchangeCall.class);

    private final HttpsExchange sexchange;

    public HttpsExchangeCall(Server server, HttpExchange exchange) {
        this(server, exchange, true);
    }

    public HttpsExchangeCall(Server server, HttpExchange exchange, boolean confidential) {
        super(server, exchange, confidential);
        if (exchange instanceof HttpsExchange) {
            sexchange = (HttpsExchange) exchange;
        } else {
            sexchange = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Certificate> getCertificates() {

        if (sexchange == null) {
            log.debug("Cannot extract peer certificates from unsecure connection.");
            return null;
        }
        Certificate[] certs = null;
        try {
            certs = sexchange.getSSLSession().getPeerCertificates();
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Found " + (certs == null ? "no" : Integer.toString(certs.length)) + " peer certificate(s).");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Unable to find peer certificates - " + e);
        }
        List<Certificate> lcerts = null;
        if (certs != null) {
            lcerts = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
            for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
                lcerts.add(certs[i]);
            }
        }
        return lcerts;
    }

}
```

Then a copy of [HttpsServerHelper](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/2.3/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/connector/HttpsServerHelper.java)
renamed to `HttpsServerHelper2` with one line modified. Replace the line

`HttpsServerHelper.this.handle(new HttpExchangeCall(getHelped(),`

with the line:

`HttpsServerHelper2.this.handle(new HttpsExchangeCall(getHelped(),`

This helper needs to be registered:

`Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers().add(new HttpsServerHelper2(null));`

and creating a `Server` now becomes very explicit:

```java
Component component = new Component();
Server server = new Server(
        (Context) null, Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTPS),
        (String) null, Constants.PORT_TEST, component.getServers().getNext(), 
        HttpsServerHelper2.class.getName()
    );
component.getServers().add(server);
```

I'm hoping Restlet's own `HttpExchangeCall` will be updated to extract the certificates:
it is a minor fix and saves a lot of unneeded code required to work around the issue.

In the mean time, you can find all the source code (using Restlet 2.3.4) and a working example in the 
[restlet-clientcert](https://github.com/intercommit/restlet-clientcert) Github project.

Answer (score -1):

This method should provide what you are looking for: request.getClientInfo().getCertificates()
http://restlet.com/learn/javadocs/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/data/ClientInfo.html

You can also retrieve the cipher suites

Comment: as you see in the OP the code you post is exactly the one I use, but does not work. I'm self hosting the restlet, could be this a problem?

Comment: which container are you using, is it jetty, tomcat or what?

Comment: @tom I'm self hosting the http listening: ie use restlet for listening.

Comment: @JeromeLouvel Can you take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32626473/3080094 and maybe update Restlet's source code?